# Ceiling Fan wires Always hot

Tags: ceiling-fan

I knew there was another reason I came here to ask.

I started removing the caps, but my guarding angel told me use Phase tester, use phase tester dummy !

So I did use it, and to my surprise the **red+blue** connected together are hot all the time. Regardless of the wall switches position.

How is that possible?

Obviously now I have to go outside and find the circuit breaker to kill the power before proceeding (I hate that), what are the wall switches for ?

Can someone now tell me with 2 switches how could I turn the light and fan separately.

I disconnect the Cap 1 (from bottom), and the lights still turn on/off.

I can not try the fan it is partially disassembeled.

[image: hot hot]

[![hot all the time][2]][2]

Comment: I never put my trust in just the switch except for changing a light bulb.  A switch only breaks one wire, if you find more than one wire you never know if the others are dead or live.

Comment: The switch could be miswired to break the neutral instead of the hot. This has the same net effect of turning the lights on and off, but leaves the circuit energized and is dangerous for the electrician. Also, switches can be easily flipped by another house occupant without realizing what impact they're having, while nobody will "go outside and find the breaker" to turn them on because "everyone hates that".

Comment: You have the link text for a 2nd image, but the reference for it is missing. You may want to remove the text or reupload the 2nd image if it's helpful. Additionally, where in the world are you? Blue and red are legal colors for Hot in the US, but are less common, so it's unclear. Is the blue wire leading into the fan's wiring or is it coming from the wall?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, black is switched at the wall for the light; Red is always hot for the fan so it can be controlled from the ceiling fan itself.  If you open up the box with the switch in it, you'll probably find that the red going to the fan is nutted to the black before the switch.

If you want to have two switches in your switch box, hook one switch up to the black going to the ceiling fan (will control the light), and the other switch to the red (feeding it from the black power coming into the wall switch box) which will control the fan on/off.

Comment: I already have separate wall switches for fan and light.

Comment: @Ruskes but someone wired it up like you don't apparently.  you'll have to get in the switch to see.

Comment: @TigerGuy  I disconnected the black and white (the first bottom plug). I can still switch the light, while the second plug (red+blue) remains hot all the time regardless of the switch position.